# Replaced my Windows hard drive, and now the Grub Menu is gone

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-10, grub-efi

So I recently had to get my windows hard drive replaced with a bigger drive, and I have ubuntu 20.10 loaded on a separate drive, but now I can't access the Grub menu even through BIOS. It only gives me one option, Windows, but when I use my 20.04 install drive, it recognizes that my other drive has ubuntu on it, as well as windows on my other drive. How do I get the Grub menu to show back up?

Comment: If UEFI then likely the replaced drive contained the EFI partition with both bootloaders; the new drive doesn't > GRUB must be reinstalled. If BIOS then likely the replaced drive was the boot drive; reinstalling Windows only its bootloader is installed in the MBR > GRUB must be reinstalled.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Comment: How would I go about reinstalling grub?

Comment: The link in the previous comments covers all the possible situations.